# Reorder of Tuple members in scala

Tags: scala, tuples

How can I reorder members of a tuple ? I have a list of tuples of 2 as below

```
((115,vp,London,1001),(2,ZIP1,ZIP2))
```

I want to reorder the tuple as

```
 ((vp,London), ( 115,1001,2,ZIP1,ZIP2) )
```

Comment: Is the text vp, London always going to appear in the same position? If yes, then it is easy. You just have to write a map function!

Comment: Yes they will be in same position . I'm new to scala so struggling to write a function for this. Can you point out a tutorial or an example for this ?

Answer (score 2):

So based on your assumption that the elements of the tuple appear in the same position, you can do the following:

```
val tpl = Seq(((115,"vp","London",1001),(2,"ZIP1","ZIP2")))

tpl.map {
  case (elem1, elem2) => ((elem1._2, elem1._3), (elem1._1, elem1._4, elem2._1, elem2._2, elem2._3))
}
```

A much better way would be to use case classes instead of tuples like this! You can box the elements of your tuple into a case class and then map is as you want it!